# Returning objects with Jayrock

Tags: .net, json, jayrock

I am using [Jayrock](http://jayrock.berlios.de/) to form a web service in .NET for my iOS app and I'm following [this tutorial.](http://www.dizzey.com/development/consuming-asp-net-web-services-in-ios-part1/) This is all good and I can get it to work fine returning basic strings using code like this:

```
[Jayrock.JsonRpc.JsonRpcMethod("Echo")]
[Jayrock.JsonRpc.JsonRpcHelp("Simple echo method, takes string input and returns it")]
public string Echo(string input)
{
    return input;
}
```

When it comes to writing my actual web service, how to I get it to return a custom JSON object with numbers and arrays etc? If you could give a code example too that would be awesome.

I've had a google around and a search here, but haven't really been able to find much that helps me. I know it's a basic question, but I'm totally stumped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All sorted now. I just needed to define a class and return an object from the function, like this:

```
[Jayrock.JsonRpc.JsonRpcMethod("GetPerson")]
public object GetPerson(string name, int age)
{
    person foo = new person(name, age);
    return foo;
}

public class person
{
    public string Name;
    public int Age;
    public person() { }
    public person(string name, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }
}
```